# UICollectionView cell sizes

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/a/13555814/1678391 was answered about setting variable sized cells in a UICollectionViewController. I'm trying to figure out how to do this with a UICollectionView object contained in a UIViewController. GetSizeForItem is what I need but don't see where to get it.

My implementation adds a UICollectionView to my UIViewController via Xcode. In my code I'm doing the following;

```cs
public partial class CustomViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        collectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(MyCell), cellId);
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        collectionView.Source = new CollectionViewSource(items, cellId);
    }

    class CollectionViewSource : UICollectionViewSource
    {
    }

    class MyCell : UICollectionViewCell
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [http://docs.go-mono.com](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M:MonoTouch.UIKit.UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.GetSizeForItem) `GetSizeForItem` is available only for `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` class.

To use that method you should implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` subclass and assing it to `Delegate` property of `UICollectionViewController`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792350/how-can-i-provide-getsizeforitem-implementation-in-uicollectionviewcontroller).

Comment: I'm not using a UICollectionViewController though. Just UICollectionView within a UIViewController. Is setting the size only possible if using UICollectionViewController? Thanks

Comment: You can (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291889/how-can-we-use-uicollectionview-without-an-uicollectionviewcontroller). Try to set second parameter in `UICollectionView`'s constructor or set `UICollectionView`'s `CollectionViewLayout` property later.

Comment: Can't seem to get the delegate subclass to be called.                 

flowLayoutDelegate = new CollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout(); 
lineLayout = new CollectionViewFlowLayout(); 
collectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(MyCell), CellId); 
collectionView.CollectionViewLayout = lineLayout; 
collectionView.Delegate = flowLayoutDelegate;

Comment: You created basic `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` class, which is using default values. Instead, you should to subclass `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and override `GetSizeForItem` method.

Comment: For demo purpose, I forked oficial SimpleCollectionView demo project (https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/SimpleCollectionView) and implemented subclass `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. See `CustomFlowLayoutDelegate` class implementation and usage in demo at https://bitbucket.org/MaximKorobov/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout-demo

Comment: My code above is a subclassed `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. The sample you show above is based on a `UICollectionViewController`. Mine is based on a `UICollectionView`. I've downloaded and run your sample. The delegate stuff is basically what I'm doing. I've added a view to your sample with what I'm doing. I've placed it on dropbox at (https://www.dropbox.com/s/90isdyt9er438xa/CollectionViewSample.zip).

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to solve it without using the UICollectionViewController?